# Changing var/www to something else

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu on a `Oracle VM Virtual box`, and installed `Apache` etc.

How do I change the `var/www` folder that Apache uses, to something else? Can I simply rename it? I'm, trying to change it to `nordy/core`, in place of `var/www`.

Can I create a separate folder called `nordy/core` and place my html files there? One of the reasons I did not do this it because I noticed that `var/` has several other folders that will not be created if I simply create a new folder. So, I'm guessing the site wont work.

I'd like to store my `html` and `php` files in a folder `nordy/core` so `Apache` can use it from there. Can I simply create a folder `nordy/core` and point `Apache` to it in `Apache's` configuration?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive of your `apache2.conf` file. You may find this file at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
DocumentRoot "/nordy/core"
```

Then restart your *apache* process.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: So I need to create folders `nordy\core` and change the DocumentRoot, is that all? No need of copying all those files in var/ to the folders  I create?